# Need to create jquery password prompt (should be simple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, password-protection

So I made a website for a scavenger hunt i am hosting, but I need a password prompt to come up nearly every page to make sure they have completed the challenge to move on. I am using Jquery and the only way to get the password promt to show up is after i refresh the page which is no good. I need a way to link one page to another, and show a password prompt before they can see the page. Here is the important html. Also, if you can. Whenever I refresh the page all of the css seems to dissapear and im left with the text. If you can please help with that.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../themes/scavenger-hunt.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Publish/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
  <body> 
<script language="javascript">
var password
var pass1="123"

password=prompt('Please enter password to view page')
if (password==pass1)
alert('password correct! Press ok to continue.')

else{
  window.location="index.html";
  alert('password incorrect! Redirecting')
}

</script>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Hint 1</h1>

  </div>
```

Comment: How secure does this need to be? Because if I was on your scavenger hunt I would bypass your password validation in ten seconds and win.

Comment: I see no jquery code.

Comment: @mrtsherman it doesnt have to be that secure, plus its mobile so its a little harder to bypass.

Comment: @Dave the Jquery is below. I just said its jquery because maybe that is part of the problem. if you want i could show the entire page

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle this, but here are two. One easier than the other. The first way I would do this is to have all the content on the page, but have it hidden on page load. If password is entered properly then it displays the page.

```
body { display:none; }

if (password == pass1) { $('body').show(); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5JyTy/

The other would be to use AJAX and only request/display the content if the password is actually correct.

```
if (password == pass1) { $('body').load('ajax/test.html'); }
```

Comment: Its not that, although that does help a little. The problem seems to be the way that the page is loaded. The page loads with an ajax loader (in other words it loads differently). I am using the Jquery mobile with theme. When i tried loading it on a webpage without the theme it works perfectly. Here is the website if that would help (click on hint 1 then refresh) http://sh.atwebpages.com/team1/home.html . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call and jquery msg plugin, it is nice and simple

http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/jquery-blockui-alternative-with-jquery-msg-plugin/